# how can I keep the tab bar order consistent but change the default view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have several view controllers connected to my tabbarcontroller. Each is named accordingly, FirstVC, SecondVC etc. When I am on let's say ThirdVC and press a button, I want it to bring up another VC, let's call it ThirdChildVC, and then have a button on ThirdChildVC which returns to the ThirdVC. The only way I can do this is by including the following code:

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(setupRootViewController1)];`

and calling another method let's call it setupRVC1 which is identical to setupRVC (see below) except that the order of VC's presented in the tab. However, I would prefer to be able to keep the order of the tabbaritems, so that it always shows FirstVC, SecondVC etc. in order but be able to present the ThirdVC as the default VC instead when the button on ThirdChildVC is pressed.

```
- (void)setupRVC
{
    UIViewController *firstVC = [[FirstVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *secondVC = [[SecondVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *fourthVC = [[FourthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *fifthVC = [[FifthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FifthVC" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC, fourthVC, fifthVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

- (void)setupRVC1
{
    UIViewController *firstVC = [[FirstVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *secondVC = [[SecondVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *fourthVC = [[FourthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthVC" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *fifthVC = [[FifthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FifthVC" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[ThirdVC, FirstVC, SecondVC, ThirdVC, FourthVC, FifthVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a Navigation Controller for each for your View Controllers and then add all the Navigation Controllers into in the TabBar Controller. Here is an example from an App I created

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [@[] mutableCopy];
WorkingTableViewController *workingTableVC = [[WorkingTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *workingNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:workingTableVC];

ClosedTableViewController *closedTableVC = [[ClosedTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *closedNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:closedTableVC];

[tabBarItems addObject:workingNavController];
[tabBarItems addObject:closedNavController];

tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarItems;
```

Once you have that set up, each time you tab into a different VC, you should be able to push and pop view controllers into the navigation stack without having to rebuild anything.

EDIT: Try this out and let me know if it works

```
UIViewController *firstVC = [[FirstVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];

UIViewController *secondVC = [[SecondVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];

UIViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdVC];

UIViewController *fourthVC = [[FourthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fourthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fourthVC];

UIViewController *fifthVC = [[FifthVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"FifthVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *fifthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fifthVC];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, fourthNavController, fifthNavController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: that's great, but what is the ClosedTableViewController?

Comment: ClosedTableViewController is just a subclass of UITableViewController. As I mentioned those are just classes from my project. I'll update the code to use your classes.